# Bad Base64 Error while using decode

Tags: android, base64

I'm using the following code to encode a url and then decode it and use it in my project but i keep getting errors and the app crashes when i try to load a url on this code

any guidance is appreciated

```
private static String getURL() {
    String base64URL = "http://www.domain.dom/folder/folder2/2.json";
    byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64URL, Base64.NO_CLOSE);
    String text = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return text;}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64
```

Comment: `"http://www.domain.dom/folder/folder2/2.json"` is not a valid Base64 string ... Perhaps you want to download the data from that URL first?

Comment: Why is that not a valid base64 string?

Comment: Because it isn't in base64 at all.  Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: Also-  encoding a URL in base 64 would be really really weird.  There's pretty much no reason to ever do that.  The purpose of Base64 is to encode binary data into a text string as a hack to send it somewhere that sends text.  A URL is already text, so using it would be pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, Base64.NO_WRAP or Base64.NO_PADDING this both are working for me.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Tried but crash again